# UIView touchesBegan not being called

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, touch

I have created a subclass of `UIView` and added in Views by referencing an xib file.

I overrided the `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnd` functions in order to have customized effect of "color changes when user presses on this view".

Below is this subclass:

```
class CustomUIView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!

    override init (frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init? (coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit () {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomUIView", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.frame = self.bounds
        contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("touch begin")
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("touch ended")
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    }

}
```

However, `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnd` are never called.

I googled and stackoverflowed, tried for 3 hours already, but cannot find any working solution to this simple question....

Below are what I have tried:

1. Made sure all superviews have UserInteraction enabled. I even
   captured View Hierarchy to check this.
2. Added an `IBAction` of touchUpInside to see whether this IBAction can be triggered. The answer is yes.
3. Subclass UIControl instead and override `beginTracking` instead. But it is also not triggered.

Below are the properties I can see from ViewHierarchy of this CustomView:

1. It is enabled
2. User Interaction Enabled On
3. Multiple Touch Off
4. Alpha 1
5. Background `<nil color>` (I have also tried to set it to have a color. Not working.)
6. Opaque On
7. Hidden Off
8. Clears Graphics Context On
9. Clip to Bounds Off
10. Autoresize Subviews On

Help very much appreciated!

Comment: what is `contentView `?

Comment: The root view of the xib file. But as you can see I havent used it yet

Comment: From your code, I suspect that all the touch events sent to your custom view are received on `contentView`. Try to disable user interaction on `contentView`.

Comment: Please visit and read the discussion column
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621142-touchesbegan

Comment: I did a test project with such code and `touches` are working fine. Attached `CustomUIView` from a storyboard, commented `contentView`. Try yourself.

Comment: Did you tried Setting view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

Comment: Aldo try checking https://github.com/RockinGarg/Moving-views-.git

Comment: Is your init method calling or not? This happens due to your customview frame not matched with your contenview

Comment: @FahriAzimov You are correct. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Fahri Azimov 's comment, the reason is `contentView` has User Interaction Enabled On. Therefore it consumed all touch events before passing to `CustomUIView`. I have upvoted his comment.

The lesson is, the rootView of the xib file is not `CustomUIView` itself but one of its child.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try this, its due to frame of your **CustomView**

```
class CustomUIView: UIView {

    var contentView: UIView!
    override init (frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init? (coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func loadFromNib() -> UIView {
                let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
                let nib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: type(of: self)), bundle: bundle)
                let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView
                return view
        }
    private func commonInit () {
        contentView = self.loadFromNib()
        addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.frame = self.bounds
        self .isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("touch begin")
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("touch ended")
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    }

}
```

I can see a logs in console

[image]

Drag one **UIView** in your **ViewController** and set your **customview** class as **CustomUIView**

[image]